# SCSS - merging two the same selectors?

Tags: css, sass

I'm using a project that has defined `body` (along with couple of other selectors) in multiple places (withing `typo.scss`, `defaults` etc.). My question is - can I somehow merge them into one? I tried extending, but it didn't help.

Code example is something like this:

```
file-1
body { background: white; }

file-2
body { font-size: 16px; }
```

And so.

Comment: So you want to keep the selectors but define them in one place?

Comment: I want to define selectors in multiple files but have output in one combined selector.

Comment: That sounds like `@extend` to me.

Comment: No. Extending the same selectors does nothing.